# Google Drive Picker: Use Feature.MINE_ONLY along with Feature.SUPPORT_DRIVES

Tags: google-drive-api, google-picker, google-drive-shared-drive, google-drive-picker

I am trying to create a Google Drive Picker that displays the following views:

1. A "folder" view, displaying the folder tree of the current user, allowing him to only pick files that the current user owns
2. A "recent" view, displaying the latest opened files, that the current user owns
3. A "shared drives" view (note: previously named "team drives"), displaying the current user's shared drives that he has access to (he his not owner of the files, as shared drives files are owned by the G Suite platform of the user)

**First attempt: `Feature.MINE_ONLY` with `Feature.SUPPORT_DRIVES`**

The first thing I tried was to enable both features `MINE_ONLY` and `SUPPORT_DRIVES` on the `PickerBuilder`, however it causes the "shared drives" view to be empty, because the user is not owner of the files in shared drives (see explanation above).

**Second attempt: `Features.SUPPORT_DRIVE` + `setOwnedByMe(true)`**

The second thing I tried was to only enable the `SUPPORT_DRIVES` feature, and use the `setOwnedByMe(true)` method on "folder" and "recent" views.

It almost works as expected, BUT the "folder" view is not displaying folders, because the `setOwnedByMe` function cannot be called along with the `setIncludeFolders` view ([reference](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/reference#DocsView)).

Following is a simplified version of my code for the second attempt (I intentionally did not put the authentication code):

```js
var googlePicker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder();

// KO: DOES NOT DISPLAY THE FOLDERS
var folderView = new google.picker.DocsView().
    //setIncludeFolders(true). // -> cannot be used with setOwnedByMe, else it overrides it
    setOwnedByMe(true).
    setParent('root');

// OK
var recentFilesView = new google.picker.DocsView(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS).
    setOwnedByMe(true);

// OK
var sharedDriveview = new google.picker.DocsView().
    setIncludeFolders(true).
    setSelectFolderEnabled(false).
    setEnableDrives(true);

googlePicker.enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.SUPPORT_DRIVES); // previously named SUPPORT_TEAM_DRIVES
//googlePicker.enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MINE_ONLY); // NOT working properly with setEnableDrives

googlePicker.
    addView(folderView).
    addView(recentFilesView).
    addView(sharedDriveview);

googlePicker.build().setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*Unfortunately it looks like this is not possible to do.*

#### Reasoning:

As you pointed out in your question, the issue here boils down to these three things:

1. To view Shared Drives, `DocsView.setEnableDrives()` needs to be set to `true`, and `Feature.SUPPORT_DRIVES` needs to be on. This can be used in conjunction with both `DocsView.setOwnedByMe()` and `DocsView.setInculudeFolders()` on their own.
2. To view files that are owned by the current user, `DocsView.setOwnedByMe()` needs to be set to `true`, or `Feature.MINE_ONLY` needs to be on. `Docsview.setOwnedByMe()` can be used with `DocsView.setEnableDrives()`, but **not** with `DocsView.setIncludeFolders()`.
3. To view Folders in the Drive view, `DriveView.setIncludeFolders()` needs to be set to `true`, but can not be set at the same time as `DriveView.setOwnedByMe()` as the value of `DriveView.setOwnedByMe()` is ignored when `DriveView.setIncludeFolders()` is set.

#### Possible workaround:

As a Picker is only able to render one view at a time, you can create a method of taking information from the user of whether to access a Shared Drive or a Personal Drive before the Picker is created and set the features and includes for the custom render. This could be done in a multitude of ways (such as a button, HTML radio button or bootstrap tab) which changes which Picker is viweable on the page.

#### Feature Request:

I have filed a Feature Request for this on your behalf on Google's Issue Tracker. This Feature Request can be found [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142302305), which you can give a star (☆) in the top left to let Google know more people wish for this request.

#### References:

- [Full Picker Documentation](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs)
- [DoceView Reference of Drive Picker](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/reference#DocsView)
- [Feature Reference of Drive Picker](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/reference#Feature)
- [Display the Google Picker Drive API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/reference#Feature)
- [Feature Request on Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142302305)