# Failed to get the driveId in the callback of the google picker in shared drive

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api, google-drive-shared-drive, google-picker, google-drive-picker

I am trying to get the shared drive id in the callback of the google picker. The response I am getting is attached in screenshot[image]

These are the scopes for getting the drive data
[image: These are the scopes for getting the drive data]

Following is the code for creating picker

```
let view = new google.picker.DocsView()
            .setOwnedByMe(false)
            .setParent(vm.folderLocationId)
            .setEnableDrives(true)
            .setMimeTypes('application/vnd.google-apps.folder')
            .setSelectFolderEnabled(true);

const picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
          .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN)
          .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED)
          .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.SUPPORT_DRIVES)
          .setDeveloperKey(vm.api_key)
          .setAppId(APP_ID)
          .setOAuthToken(vm.access_token)
          .addView(view)
          .addView(new google.picker.DocsUploadView())
          .setCallback(pickerCallback)
          .build();
      picker.setVisible(true);

async function pickerCallback(data) {
  console.log('data', data)
}
```

This is the response of console.log
[image]

I am using gapi not google drive api for doing this.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide your existing code along with the error you encountered so that we can replicate your problem?

Comment: @George I have added more details to the question. Please have a look. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried [Implementing shared drive support](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/enable-shareddrives#drive-api-v3)? In your `pickerCallback` function you can use the [files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/enable-shareddrives#search_for_content_on_a_shared_drive) method to search for shared drives and include `supportAllDrives=true` in your request

Comment: @George I have already checked this out. But for files.list, I need driveId which I am unable to get in the data of the callback of the picker.

Comment: By any chance, is this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58231453/google-drive-picker-use-feature-mine-only-along-with-feature-support-drives?rq=1) helpful in any way to your problem?

Answer (score 1):

As I was trying to get the drive id by which I can access the folders of the shared drive.

I did it by adding the parameter of `supportsAllDrives: true`

[image]